# Parameter missing when adding item in cart in shopify

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, shopify

I am getting this error in shopify every time I click *add to cart* button.

parameter missing or invalid:id with that request id:

Request ID: 08567c18-c095-4238-95e5-92e794c9bfbf

This is my code from product.template.liquid

```css
<div class="product-template__container page-width" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="ProductSection-{{ section.id }}" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="product" data-enable-history-state="true"><meta itemprop="name" content="{{ product.title }}"><meta itemprop="url" content="{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}"><meta itemprop="image" content="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: '800x' }}"> {
  % comment %
}

Get first variant,
or deep linked one {
  % endcomment %
}

{
  %- assign current_variant=product.selected_or_first_available_variant -%
}

{
  %- assign product_thumb_size='110x110' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_image_zoom_size='1024x1024' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_image_scale='2' -%
}

{
  %- assign enable_zoom=section.settings.enable_zoom -%
}

{
  % case section.settings.image_size %
}

{
  % when 'small' %
}

{
  %- assign product_image_width='medium-up--one-third' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_description_width='medium-up--two-thirds' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_thumbnail_width='medium-up--one-third' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_image_size='345x' -%
}

{
  % when 'medium' %
}

{
  %- assign product_image_width='medium-up--one-half' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_description_width='medium-up--one-half' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_thumbnail_width='medium-up--one-quarter' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_image_size='530x' -%
}

{
  % when 'large' %
}

{
  %- assign product_image_width='medium-up--two-thirds' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_description_width='medium-up--one-third' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_thumbnail_width='medium-up--one-fifth' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_image_size='720x' -%
}

{
  % when 'full' %
}

{
  %- assign product_image_width='' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_description_width='' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_thumbnail_width='medium-up--one-eighth' -%
}

{
  %- assign product_image_size='1090x' -%
}

{
  %- assign enable_zoom=false -%
}

{
  % endcase %
}

<div class="grid product-single"><div class="grid__item product-single__photos {{ product_image_width }}{% if section.settings.image_size == 'full' %} product-single__photos--full{% endif %}"> {
  %- assign featured_img_src=current_variant.featured_image.src | default: product.featured_image.src -%
}

{
  %- assign featured_img_alt=current_variant.featured_image.alt | default: product.featured_image.alt -%
}

<div id="FeaturedImageZoom-{{ section.id }}" class="product-single__photo{% if product.images.size > 1 %} product-single__photo--has-thumbnails{% endif %}" {
  % if enable_zoom %
}

data-zoom="{{ featured_img_src | img_url: product_image_zoom_size, scale: product_image_scale }}" {
  % endif %
}

><img src="{{ featured_img_src | img_url: product_image_size, scale: product_image_scale }}" alt="{{ featured_img_alt }}" id="FeaturedImage-{{ section.id }}" class="product-featured-img{% if enable_zoom %} js-zoom-enabled{% endif %}"></div> {
  % if product.images.size>1 %
}

{
  % if product.images.size>3 %
}

{
  %- assign enable_thumbnail_slides=true -%
}

{
  % endif %
}

<div class="thumbnails-wrapper{% if enable_thumbnail_slides == true %} thumbnails-slider--active{% endif %}"> {
  % if enable_thumbnail_slides==true %
}

<button type="button" class="btn btn--link medium-up--hide thumbnails-slider__btn thumbnails-slider__prev thumbnails-slider__prev--{{ section.id }}"> {
  % include 'icon-chevron-left' %
}

<span class="icon__fallback-text"> {
  {
    'sections.slideshow.previous_slide' | t
  }
}

</span></button> {
  % endif %
}

<ul class="grid grid--uniform product-single__thumbnails product-single__thumbnails-{{ section.id }}"> {
  % for image in product.images %
}

<li class="grid__item {{ product_thumbnail_width }} product-single__thumbnails-item"><a href="{{ image.src | img_url: product_image_size, scale: product_image_scale }}" class="text-link product-single__thumbnail product-single__thumbnail--{{ section.id }}" {
  % if enable_zoom %
}

data-zoom="{{ image.src | img_url: product_image_zoom_size, scale: product_image_scale }}" {
  % endif %
}

><img class="product-single__thumbnail-image" src="{{ image.src | img_url: product_thumb_size, scale: product_image_scale }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}"></a></li> {
  % endfor %
}

</ul> {
  % if enable_thumbnail_slides==true %
}

<button type="button" class="btn btn--link medium-up--hide thumbnails-slider__btn thumbnails-slider__next thumbnails-slider__next--{{ section.id }}"> {
  % include 'icon-chevron-right' %
}

<span class="icon__fallback-text"> {
  {
    'sections.slideshow.next_slide' | t
  }
}

</span></button> {
  % endif %
}

</div> {
  % endif %
}

</div><div class="grid__item {{ product_description_width }}"><div class="product-single__meta"><h1 itemprop="name" class="product-single__title"> {
  {
    product.title
  }
}

</h1> {
  % if section.settings.show_vendor %
}

<p itemprop="brand" class="product-single__vendor"> {
  {
    product.vendor
  }
}

</p> {
  % endif %
}

<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="{{ shop.currency }}"><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/{% if product.available %}InStock{% else %}OutOfStock{% endif %}"><p class="product-single__price product-single__price-{{ section.id }}{% unless current_variant.available %} product-price--sold-out{% endunless %}"> {
  % if current_variant.compare_at_price>current_variant.price %
}

<span class="visually-hidden"> {
  {
    'products.product.regular_price' | t
  }
}

</span><s id="ComparePrice-{{ section.id }}"> {
  {
    current_variant.compare_at_price | money
  }
}

</s><span class="product-price__price product-price__price-{{ section.id }} product-price__sale product-price__sale--single"><span id="ProductPrice-{{ section.id }}" itemprop="price" content="{{ current_variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}"> {
  {
    current_variant.price | money
  }
}

</span><span class="product-price__sale-label product-price__sale-label-{{ section.id }}"> {
  {
    'products.product.on_sale' | t
  }
}

</span></span> {
  % else %
}

<span class="visually-hidden"> {
  {
    'products.product.regular_price' | t
  }
}

</span><s id="ComparePrice-{{ section.id }}" class="hide"> {
  {
    current_variant.compare_at_price | money
  }
}

</s><span class="product-price__price product-price__price-{{ section.id }}"><span id="ProductPrice-{{ section.id }}" itemprop="price" content="{{ current_variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}"> {
  {
    current_variant.price | money
  }
}

</span><span class="product-price__sale-label product-price__sale-label-{{ section.id }} hide"> {
  {
    'products.product.on_sale' | t
  }
}

</span></span> {
  % endif %
}

</p><form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="product-form product-form-{{ section.id }}{% unless section.settings.show_variant_labels %} product-form--hide-variant-labels{% endunless %}" data-section="{{ section.id }}"><!-- {
  % unless product.options.size==1 and product.variants[0].title=='Default Title' %
}

{
  % for option in product.options_with_values %
}

<div class="selector-wrapper js product-form__item"><label {
  % if option.name=='default' %
}

class="label--hidden" {
  % endif %
}

for="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}"> {
  {
    option.name
  }
}

</label><select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-{{ section.id }} product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}" data-index="option{{ forloop.index }}"> {
  % for value in option.values %
}

<option value="{{ value | escape }}" {
  % if option.selected_value==value %
}

selected="selected" {
  % endif %
}

> {
  {
    value
  }
}

</option> {
  % endfor %
}

</select></div> {
  % endfor %
}

{
  % endunless %
}

--> {
  % if product.available and product.variants.size>1 %
}

{
  % for option in product.options %
}

{
  % include 'swatch' with option %
}

{
  % endfor %
}

{
  % endif %
}

<!--select name="id" id="ProductSelect-{{ section.id }}" data-section="{{ section.id }}" class="product-form__variants no-js"> {
  % for variant in product.variants %
}

{
  % if variant.available %
}

<option {
  % if variant==product.selected_or_first_available_variant %
}

selected="selected" {
  % endif %
}

value="{{ variant.id }}"> {
  {
    variant.title
  }
}

</option> {
  % else %
}

<option disabled="disabled"> {
  {
    variant.title
  }
}

- {
  {
    'products.product.sold_out' | t
  }
}

</option> {
  % endif %
}

{
  % endfor %
}

</select--> {
  % if section.settings.show_quantity_selector %
}

<div class="product-form__item product-form__item--quantity"><label for="Quantity"> {
  {
    'products.product.quantity' | t
  }
}

</label><input type="number" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="product-form__input" pattern="[0-9]*"></div> {
  % endif %
}

<div class="product-form__item product-form__item--submit"><button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart-{{ section.id }}" {
  % unless current_variant.available %
}

disabled="disabled" {
  % endunless %
}

class="btn product-form__cart-submit{% if product.options.size == 1 and product.variants[0].title == 'Default Title' %} product-form__cart-submit--small{% endif %}"><span id="AddToCartText-{{ section.id }}"> {
  % unless current_variant.available %
}

{
  {
    'products.product.sold_out' | t
  }
}

{
  % else %
}

{
  {
    'products.product.add_to_cart' | t
  }
}

{
  % endunless %
}

</span></button></div></form></div><p> {
  % if section.settings.show_share_buttons %
}

{
  % include 'social-sharing',
  share_title: product.title, share_permalink: product.url, share_image: product %
}

{
  % endif %
}

</p></div></div></div></div><div class="product-single__description rte" itemprop="description"><div><ul class="tabs"><li><a href="#tab-1">Product Description</a></li><li><a href="#tab-2">Size Chart</a></li><li><a href="#tab-3">Shipping and Return</a></li></ul><div id="tab-1"> {
  {
    product.description
  }
}

</div><div id="tab-2"> {
  {
    page.size.chart
  }
}

</div><div id="tab-3"> {
  {
    page.shipping.return
  }
}

</div></div></div> {
  % if collection %
}

<div class="text-center return-link-wrapper"><a href="{{ collection.url }}" class="btn btn--secondary btn--has-icon-before return-link"> {
  % include 'icon-arrow-left' %
}

{
  {
    'products.product.back_to_collection' | t: title: collection.title
  }
}

</a></div> {
  % endif %
}

{
  % unless product==empty %
}

<script type="application/json" id="ProductJson-{{ section.id }}"> {
  {
    product | json
  }
}

</script> {
  % endunless %
}

{
  % schema %
}

{
  "name": "Product pages",
  "settings": [ {
    "type": "select",
    "id": "image_size",
    "label": "Image size",
    "options": [ {
      "value": "small", "label": "Small"
    }
    ,
    {
      "value": "medium", "label": "Medium"
    }
    ,
    {
      "value": "large", "label": "Large"
    }
    ,
    {
      "value": "full", "label": "Full-width"
    }
    ],
    "default": "medium"
  }
  ,
  {
    "type": "checkbox", "id": "show_quantity_selector", "label": "Show quantity selector", "default": false
  }
  ,
  {
    "type": "checkbox", "id": "show_variant_labels", "label": "Show variant labels", "default": true
  }
  ,
  {
    "type": "checkbox", "id": "show_vendor", "label": "Show vendor", "default": false
  }
  ,
  {
    "type": "checkbox", "id": "enable_zoom", "label": "Enable image zoom", "default": true
  }
  ,
  {
    "type": "checkbox", "id": "show_share_buttons", "label": "Show social sharing buttons", "default": true
  }
  ]
}

{
  % endschema %
}

<style>ul.tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.tabs li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}

ul.tabs li a {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-image: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F5F5;
  border-color: #DDDDDD !important;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: auto;
  color: #303030;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

ul.tabs li a.active {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  color: #111111;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}

ul.tabs li:first-child a.active {
  margin-left: 0;
}

ul.tabs li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0;
}

ul.tabs li:last-child a {
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}

ul.tabs:before,
ul.tabs:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
}

ul.tabs:after {
  clear: both;
}

</style>
```

and this the code for cart template liquid.

```css
<div class="page-width" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="cart-template">

  {% if cart.item_count > 0 %}
    <div class="section-header text-center">
      <h1>{{ 'cart.general.title' | t }}</h1>
    </div>

    <form action="/cart" method="post" novalidate class="cart">
      <table>
        <thead class="cart__row cart__header">
          <th colspan="2">{{ 'cart.label.product' | t }}</th>
          <th>{{ 'cart.label.price' | t }}</th>
          <th class="text-center">{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</th>
          <th class="text-right">{{ 'cart.label.total' | t }}</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for item in cart.items %}
            <tr class="cart__row border-bottom line{{ forloop.index }} cart-flex{% if forloop.first %} border-top{% endif %}">
              <td class="cart__image-wrapper cart-flex-item">
                <a href="{{ item.url | within: collections.all }}">
                  <img class="cart__image" src="{{ item | img_url: '95x95', scale: 2 }}" alt="{{ item.title | escape }}">
                </a>
              </td>
              <td class="cart__meta small--text-left cart-flex-item">
                <div class="list-view-item__title">
                  <a href="{{ item.url }}">
                    {{ item.product.title }}
                    {% if item.quantity > 1 %}
                      <span class="medium-up--hide"><span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</span>(x{{ item.quantity }})</span>
                    {% endif %}
                  </a>
                </div>
                {% unless item.variant.title contains 'Default' %}
                  <div class="cart__meta-text">
                    {% for option in item.product.options %}
                      {{ option }}: {{ item.variant.options[forloop.index0] }}<br/>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                {% endunless %}

                {% comment %}
                  Optional, loop through custom product line items if available

                  Line item properties come in as having two parts. The first part will be passed with the default form,
                  but p.last is the actual custom property and may be blank. If it is, don't show it.

                  For more info on line item properties, visit:
                    - http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/products/how-do-I-collect-additional-information-on-the-product-page-Like-for-a-monogram-engraving-or-customization
                {% endcomment %}
                {%- assign property_size = item.properties | size -%}
                {% if property_size > 0 %}
                  <div class="cart__meta-text">
                    {% for p in item.properties %}
                      {% unless p.last == blank %}
                        {{ p.first }}:

                        {% comment %}
                          Check if there was an uploaded file associated
                        {% endcomment %}
                        {% if p.last contains '/uploads/' %}
                          <a href="{{ p.last }}">{{ p.last | split: '/' | last }}</a>
                        {% else %}
                          {{ p.last }}
                        {% endif %}
                      {% endunless %}
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                {% endif %}

                <p class="small--hide">
                  <a href="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0" class="btn btn--small btn--secondary cart__remove">{{ 'cart.general.remove' | t }}</a>
                </p>
              </td>
              <td class="cart__price-wrapper cart-flex-item">
                {{ item.price | money }}

                {% for discount in item.discounts %}
                  <div class="cart-item__discount medium-up--hide">{{ discount.title }}</div>
                {% endfor %}

                <div class="cart__edit medium-up--hide">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn--secondary btn--small js-edit-toggle cart__edit--active" data-target="line{{ forloop.index }}">
                    <span class="cart__edit-text--edit">{{ 'cart.general.edit' | t }}</span>
                    <span class="cart__edit-text--cancel">{{ 'cart.general.cancel' | t }}</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="cart__update-wrapper cart-flex-item text-right">
                <a href="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0" class="btn btn--small btn--secondary cart__remove medium-up--hide">{{ 'cart.general.remove' | t }}</a>
                <div class="cart__qty">
                  <label for="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-label">{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</label>
                  <input class="cart__qty-input" type="number" name="updates[]" id="updates_{{ item.key }}" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn--small cart__update medium-up--hide" value="{{ 'cart.general.update' | t }}">
              </td>
              <td class="text-right small--hide">
                {% if item.original_line_price != item.line_price %}
                  <div class="cart-item__original-price"><s>{{ item.original_line_price | money }}</s></div>
                {% endif %}

                <div>
                  {{ item.line_price | money }}
                </div>

                {% for discount in item.discounts %}
                  <div class="cart-item__discount">{{ discount.title }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
              </td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <footer class="cart__footer">
        <div class="grid">
          {% if section.settings.cart_notes_enable %}
            <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half cart-note">
              <label for="CartSpecialInstructions" class="cart-note__label small--text-center">{{ 'cart.general.note' | t }}</label>
              <textarea name="note" id="CartSpecialInstructions" class="cart-note__input">{{ cart.note }}</textarea>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
          <div class="grid__item text-right small--text-center{% if section.settings.cart_notes_enable %} medium-up--one-half{% endif %}">
            <div>
              <span class="cart__subtotal-title">{{ 'cart.general.subtotal' | t }}</span>
              <span class="cart__subtotal">{{ cart.total_price | money }}</span>
            </div>
            {% if cart.total_discounts > 0 %}
              <div class="cart__savings">
                {{ 'cart.general.savings' | t }}
                <span class="cart__savings-amount">{{ cart.total_discounts | money }}</span>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="cart__shipping">{{ 'cart.general.shipping_at_checkout' | t }}</div>
            <a href="collections/all" class="btn btn--secondary cart__update cart__continue--large small--hide" >{{ 'cart.general.continue_shopping' | t }}</a>
            <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn--secondary cart__update cart__update--large small--hide" value="{{ 'cart.general.update' | t }}">
            <input type="submit" name="checkout" class="btn btn--small-wide" value="{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}">
            {% if additional_checkout_buttons %}
              <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">{{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}</div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </form>
  {% else %}
    <div class="empty-page-content text-center">
      <h1>{{ 'cart.general.title' | t }}</h1>
      <p class="cart--empty-message">{{ 'cart.general.empty' | t }}</p>
      <div class="cookie-message">
        <p>{{ 'cart.general.cookies_required' | t }}</p>
      </div>
      <a href="/" class="btn btn--has-icon-after cart__continue-btn">{{ 'general.404.link' | t }}{% include 'icon-arrow-right' %}</a>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Cart page",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "cart_notes_enable",
        "label": "Enable cart notes",
        "default": false
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: Post you code we cant help you

Comment: Please can you post a link to jsfiddle/pastebin with your code, so we can see it please, as @dimmik has commented.

Comment: thank you for comment. let me paste the code

Comment: i can't even seem to paste my code in here. any idea how to paste the code? the instruction keep giving me weird statement. i will be glad if you could check out my shopify account at https://sorai-store.myshopify.com/admin/ with password : Butik616908

Comment: i manage to paste code. that is the code for product-template.liquid and cart-template.liquid.. i think maybe they are related or something. thank you

Comment: Why is your `<select name="id" id="ProductSelect-{{ section.id }}" data-section="{{ section.id }}" class="product-form__variants no-js">` commented out? At the moment you don't submit the variant id at all, it's normal for to say that the ID is missing.

Comment: @drip i think it was missing out when the colour swatch is added in. maybe deleted or something. and for the id, i thought u need to figure out the number, is it?

Comment: The `id` is the variant `id` and it's unique for each variant for each product. You MUST have a field with `name="id"` if you are not using javascript in some way to add the product in the cart, which I assume you are not using.

Comment: @drip my product variant is mostly more than 1 number. and the id is different for every variant.any idea how to insert the variant id for every colour and size?